# Why the generating function of $x^2(1-3x)^{-1}$ is $(0,0,1,3,3^2,3^3)$ instead of $(0,0,1,-3,3^2,-3^3)$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I've made this exercise. First I expanded $(1-3x)^{-1}$ and obtained:

$$1 - 3 x + 9 x^2 - 27 x^3 + 81 x^4 - 243 x^5 + 729 x^6$$

Then I took the sequence of $x^2$ which is $(0,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$ and then multitplied both sequences and obtained:

$$(0,0,1,-3,9,-27,81,\ldots)$$

And here I don't understand why the answer is $(0,0,1,-3,3^2,-3^3)$. I may have made some silly mistake but I can't spot it.

Comment: Please think again about the expansion of 1/(1-3x), the one in your question is wrong.

Comment: Oh, got it. I was just expanding with the formula. `Sum[Binomial[-1, n] (3 x)^n, {n, 0, 6}]`. But what's not clear to me is why what I made *doesn't work*. It gives almost the same numbers modulo-wise.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots
$$

Comment: Oh, got it. I was just expanding with the formula. `Sum[Binomial[-1, n] (3 x)^n, {n, 0, 6}]`. But what's not clear to me is why what I made *doesn't work*. It gives almost the same numbers modulo-wise.